# select count from sub query of the same columns MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK I need to get a count ID's but from the same table. I am not sure how to explain this so I will just show you:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM Response 
WHERE q_ID = 655 
  AND r = 1576 
  AND q_ID = 642 
  AND r = 1496
```

I would assume I would need a subquery something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID 
  FROM Response 
  WHERE q_ID = 655 
   AND r = 1576
) 
WHERE q_ID = 642 
 AND r = 1496
```

Maybe something like that would work I am just not sure.
Ok so here is what I am thinking, I need a count of ID's that are filtered twice first give me all that = q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576 then from that group count all the ID's that = q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand if you included some sample data, and a sample of the output you wanted.

Comment: The data is just rows of responses to a survey, and the output is kind of clear a count of ID

Comment: The above query you have given is not right. When you filter using the first Where clause the second WHERE clause will not given any rows as the second condition is not the subset of First WHERE condition inside the sub query.

Comment: I guess I see that now, what I need is a count of males q_ID = 655 r = 1576 that are 18-24 also q_id = 642 and r = 1496 if that helps.

Comment: @user1221399 again it is mutualy exclusive, no record can have q_id = 655 as well as q_id = 642. Your logic needs to be revised

Comment: If none of the answers below are correct that you need to clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Come on OP let me in your head what do you need?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the Joes query or this?
If you are looking to find any rows that have `q_ID` of 655 or 642 that also have `r`that's 1576 or 1496 than this will give you that.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM Response 
WHERE q_ID  IN (655,642) 
  AND r IN (1576, 1496)
```

If you are looking for a query that returns rows that have a `q_ID` of 655 and `r` of 1576 or a `q_ID` of 642 and `r` OF 1496 then you want this.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM Response 
WHERE (q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576)
      OR (q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496)
```

If you want the second one accept @Joe's answer since he came up with this first.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct id) 
FROM Response 
WHERE (q_ID = 655 
         AND r = 1576)
      OR (q_ID = 642  
         AND r = 1496)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no duplicate Id's, it's just a job of counting the rows and the q_ID and r values form pairs it's a simple case of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Response WHERE (q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496) 
OR q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576)
```

Comment: I guess I would like to query q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496 AND from that group of ID's Query q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576 as a count.

Comment: Please edit to avoid the scrollbar.

Comment: @user1221399 what?, so you are querying where `q_id = 642` **and** from that group you want where `q_id = 655`?. The result would be an empty set

Comment: @user1221399 if `q_id = 642` then `q_id` **CAN NOT** `=655`

Comment: @Zane - there you go - are you really that petty?

Comment: @Swomble I didn't downvote you homie. I was just going to edit for user readability however fixing it wasn't six characters so I couldn't suggest the edit. So calm down I'm just trying to make your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

By includeing Q_ID and R in Group by You can identify the counts associated with that particular group.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Q_ID, R
FROM TABLE
WHERE ((q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576) OR (q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496))
GROUP BY Q_ID, R
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what they are looking for.

Comment: From the question I think this is what the user needs, see the comments below the questions. The user has given mutually exclusive conditions in his example query

Comment: I believe that OP wants a query that changes the laws of mathematics thus allowing all rows where `q_ID` equals 655 to also equal 642.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this its a little messy but its ok, I added a ID for each person that took the survey, made a dataset and added each person to the dataset with that specific trait sex age etc.. 
So I have a master set of peoples data then I just cross the tables with each other in a count and I have the count of what I am looking for. If someone else has a better solution I am all ears!

Answer (score -3):

Modify your query with this :

two options available depending upon your requirement:

if your requirement is "find any rows that have q_ID of 655 or 642 that also have r that is 1576 or 1496" then try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Response WHERE q_ID  IN (655,642) AND R IN (1576, 1496)
```

or

if your requirement is "rows that have a q_ID of 655 and r of 1576 or a q_ID of 642 and r OF 1496" then try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Response WHERE (q_ID = 655 AND r = 1576) OR (q_ID = 642 AND r = 1496)
```